# Как получить аргумент из команды

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть код

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="return")
async def Return(m: types.Message):
    await m.reply(data)
```

Мне надо, чтобы при написании /return 25 или другое число, мне возвращалось это число в сообщении бота.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто, аргументы в команде - обычный текст.

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands="return")
async def Return(m: types.Message):
    args = m.text.split()

    print(m)  # 0 => return, 1 => 25

    if len(args) < 2:
        return bot.reply_to(message, "Напишите: /return <число>")

    await m.reply(args[1])
```